# In what way was Niniveh wicked?

Tags: sin, yonah-jonah-book-of

What was so especially "wicked" about Niniveh that Jonah would have to go there?

Were they wicked in that they worshiped different god(s)? This is pretty much what every other country did.

Were they wicked in that they had high crime and murder rates?

Were they wicked in that they instituted high taxes?

Actually I am looking for how Niniveh was "different". For example, violent people, as we know, are common in all societies. So I wonder if they were unusually violent (i.e., if that was the issue).

What was it that set them apart in their wickedness?

Comment: Why high taxes?

Comment: high (income) taxes are evil for it punish people for being productive. Ask Milton Friedman (a jew). I suppose they probably have sword free zone that allow psychos to kill children and give their government justification for even more restrictions on right to bear arms. However, I want to keep the question serious.

Comment: I highly doubt that Milton Friedman actually uses the word "evil" and even more highly doubt that he was basing anything on Jewish sources.  Karl Marx and Emma Goldman were also Jews.

Comment: Actually I am looking for cases where Niniveh is "different". Violent, as we know are common in all societies. So I wonder if they are unusually violent (have higher homicide rate), and that sort of thing. Tax is robbery. Not recognizing tax as robbery means God (in Judaism) himself recognize government and their rights to tax hapless peasants, which is another issue I want to know my self.

Comment: You're welcome to [ask](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Jonah 3:8](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16185/showrashi/false/jewish/Chapter-3.htm) - see [Radak](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14261&st=&pgnum=191) - says that the sin of Ninvei was Chamas - [translated by many as robbery](http://www.aspaklaria.info/008_HET/%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%A1.htm). We see similarly in [Braishis 6:11](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=112) (or [with English](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0106.htm#11)) by the Great Flood by Noach which came upon the world for that reason.

There are others that translate Chamas differently. However it was Chamas that was the reason why Hashem was ready to destroy Ninvai.

Comment: Where does Radak say that Chamas means robbery? It means 'violence' or something along those lines. See for example its usage in Genesis 16:5

Comment: @DoubleAA, I seem to recall that a lot of verbal commentary (as in pulpit speeches) assume it means robbery as well. There must be a source somewhere that serves as the basis for this assumption.

Comment: @SethJ Well, Rashi by the flood says it is Gezel, but I don't know that we can extrapolate to everywhere.

Comment: Also, worth noting that Radak says Chamas was the biggest sin, not the only sin.

Comment: @GershonGold Exactly. It means something bad and midrashim fill in the specifics in different contexts. So I stand by not being able to extrapolate from the Mabul to Ninveh.

Comment: @DoubleAA One of the examples of their teshuva that Rabbis cite - the only one bein adam lechavero (there are ones bein adam lemakom) - is that they gave back the stolen goods. That seems to support SethJ and GershonGold...

Comment: Whoa whoa woah. The Zohar never says robbery, bava kamma says it isn't robbery, and midrash rabbah says it's avoda zara, gilui arayot and shefichut damim. Not to mention the other opinions on the page (Ibn Ezra: rape. Ohr Hachayim: General Evil. Maharal: Grabbing. and more). Also **none of them** were talking in the context of Yonah.

Comment: @gt6989b It would support them if you could tell me who said that.

Comment: @DoubleAA Gemara Taanis 16a - the people of Nineveh demolished an entire castle just to return a stolen beam to its owner.

Comment: @gt6989b Good source. All it proves though is that returning stolen objects was one thing they did as repentance, not that their only still was stealing.

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36067&st=&pgnum=39&hilite=

Comment: ותאמר שרי אל אברם חמסי עליך וגו' (טז, ה)
 
היאך נופל כאן לשון חמס שעניינו גזילה, ומה ענין זה לכעסה על אברהם, וכמו"כ יש להבין הלא היא עצמה נתנה את הגר לאברהם ומה תביעה יש לה עליו.
אכן באמת יש להבין עצם הדבר שנעשה כך ותקל גבירתה בעיניה, וע"י מה נעשתה קלה בעיניה והרי ולד שפחה כמותה, ואדרבה גם ולדה עבד לשרה והיאך נקלה כבודה בעיני הגר, אלא סבורה היתה הגר כהנך דעות בפוסקים (יו"ד קס"ז ס"ט) דישראל שבא על שפחתו או קדשה הולד בן חורין דאמרינן מסתמא שחררה, ונקל כבוד גבירתה כי סברה שבת חורין היא דשחררה אברהם.

Comment: ועל זאת טענה שרה לאברהם והרי כיון שכך סבורה היא ומתנהגת על פי זה ואתה שותק לה הרי כאילו מסכים אתה לדבריה, ואיך תעשה זאת והרי גזל גמור הוא שתשחררנה שהרי היא נכסי מלוג וכמוש"כ המפרשים שהיתה הגר נכסי מלוג של שרה, ובנכסי מלוג קי"ל (יו"ד רס"ז של"ח) שאין ביד הבעל לשחררה, ואם שיחררת אותה חמסי עליך וגזל בידך.
ועל זאת השיבה אברהם הנה שפחתך בידך ואינה משוחררת ועדיין שפחתך היא.
(יעלת חן)

Comment: @DoubleAA Agree 100%, just aimed to prove that theft was definitely one of the items on the (possibly) long list. It's also the only one named in that gemara, but I'm sure there are other sources. IMO, just as by the flood that was the seal of the verdict, so too over here they suspected it as well... It is only underlined by tradition (can't quote a source, but I vaguely remember it being the Ari) that Yonah is a reincarnation of Moshe (and hence of Noach), so it would be reasonable if the sin was a similar one...

Comment: FTR, I'm not supporting any position. I was merely stating for @DoubleAA's sake that Gershon's interpretation isn't new. I've heard it before. I've also heard other explanations. It means violence, in today's Hebrew. I've also heard it means violent corruption (like extortion, violently forced sexual corruption, and all kinds of immoral activities that can fall under that umbrella).

Comment: [R Aryeh Kaplan](http://bible.ort.org/books/help.asp?action=displaytext&type=1&id=2)'s translation also renders: "violence" http://bible.ort.org/books/haftarotd4.asp?action=displaypage&book=6&chapter=3&verse=7&portion=66